# endpoint not generated in app.config when adding Service reference

Tags: c#, wcf

I need to consume some wcf, but im already stuck with adding the Service reference :)
What I do:

1. Create new Windows forms project.
2. Rightclick the project and press "Add service reference".
3. Inserts the svc addres and presses "Go".

[image]

[image]

The Service is then added, but when I look in my app.config then it only contains this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
</configuration>
```

Where is my endpoints?? Arent they supposed to be generated when adding the service reference?

Comment: Have u tried using svcUtil tool to generate reference.cs and .config file?

Comment: Sometimes the config is updated after you hit update on the service reference.

Comment: Does it work with wcftestclient.exe when you add the service URL https://foe/client.svc ?

Comment: I think there might be something wrong with the service itself... Just added some other api's and they work just fine. I will send the trouble to the creator of the api then :)

Comment: I know it's old but was it by any chance an old .net 2.0 tha was converted to .net 4.0 because i have same issue. in the same solution i add a new .net 4 winform and add reference there and bag it works but for the old .net 2.0 that was change to 4.0 the app config just screw up and changing it manually does nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just found the way to fix this. You need to uncheck the "Reuse types in referenced assemblies". I had same issue and noticed i had .net 2.0 lib within my .net 4.0 project and as the project was using legacy mode i supposed there is an issue when it comes to use WCF. Noticed that 2.0 asmx web services works perfectly for me but as i said, removing the check in the advance tab of the WCF fix this issue